E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while installing intel drivers
apt --fix-broken install:
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Corrigiendo dependencias...Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
 Listo
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libgl1-amber-dri
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0 libopengl0 libvdpau1:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
Paquetes sugeridos:
  libvdpau-va-gl1:i386
Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
  libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0 libopengl0 libvdpau1:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
6 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 11 no actualizados.
46 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/307 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 8.192 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 230263 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../0-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libglx0:amd64 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/0-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/libglx0/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes libglx0:amd64
Preparando para desempaquetar .../1-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libgl1:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/1-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/libgl1/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes libgl1:i386
Preparando para desempaquetar .../2-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando libopengl0:amd64 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/2-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/libopengl0/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes libopengl0:amd64
Preparando para desempaquetar .../3-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libglvnd0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) sobre (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/3-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/libglvnd0/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes libglvnd0:i386
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                        Preparando para desempaquetar .../4-libvdpau1_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando libvdpau1:i386 (1.5-2105~22.04) sobre (1.4-3build2) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/4-libvdpau1_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/libvdpau1/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes libvdpau1:i386
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                        Preparando para desempaquetar .../5-vdpau-driver-all_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando vdpau-driver-all:i386 (1.5-2105~22.04) sobre (1.4-3build2) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/5-vdpau-driver-all_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir el compartido `/usr/share/doc/vdpau-driver-all/changelog.Debian.gz', que es distinto de otras instancias del paquetes vdpau-driver-all:i386
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                        Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/0-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/1-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/2-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/3-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/4-libvdpau1_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-AMhDuO/5-vdpau-driver-all_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

